# Free vector space of a finite set is isomorphic to its function space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a finite set and let $F(X, \mathbb{C})$ be the space of functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. How can I show $\mathbb{C}X$, the free vector space generated by $X$  is isomorphic to the above function space? Isn't the function space infinite dimensional, so how can they be isomorphic?

Comment: $X$ is finite, so it is not infinite dimensional.

Comment: An element of $\mathbb{C}X$ is a formal sum $\sum_{k=1}^n z_k x_k$ where $X=\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$.  Do you see how to use this to build a function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map 
$$\varphi : F(X,\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}X\\
f  \mapsto \sum_{x\in X} f(x)x$$
we want to show tht this is a bijection for $X$ finite. First consider surjectivity:
let $y = \sum_{x\in X} \lambda_x x$ then this has the preimage $$z: X \to \mathbb{C} \\ x \mapsto \lambda_x.$$
Now for injectivity:
since the set $\{x\}_{x\in X} \subset \mathbb{C}X$ is linear independent by definition, we have that $0= \varphi(f)=\sum_{x\in X} f(x)x$ if and only if $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in X$, but this ust means that $f$ is the zero map, and hence we have that $\ker (\varphi) =0$ which proves injectivity.

So since $\varphi$ is injective and surjective, it is bijective. Also it is linear, which is an easy calculation, respectively as $\varphi$ is the finite sum of evalutions clear.
And so $\varphi$ is an iso